# How to teach a small router to support a VPN Protocol?

Tags: linux, router, vpn, compile

i have a small mips router [(link to tech specs - HW-Rev D3)](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-615#hardware) on my table and i was wondering how to teach it something it does actually not support.

with a exploit i figured out how to login via telnet. i have now ~2mb free space left on it. im sure this is enough to teach this mini-linux some VPN-functionalities.

i dont know anymore how to help myself in this situation, i hope you can give me some hints to get me back on this journey.

installed is the stock firmware from dlink. the stock firmware takes ~2mb of the 4mb flash.

uname -a prints following:

```
Linux 2.6.21 #1 Wed Mar 3 15:18:10 CST 2010 mips unknown
```

**I need VPN support for further working.** im pleasured for any assistance!

in open-wrt and dd-wrt packages are these functions available! but how could i port this?

available commands in the embedded system are:

> arpping, asession, ated, atp, basename, brctl, busybox, chmod, ctest, chnet, cut, cat, cp, date, devconf, dhcpxmlpatch, dirname, dyndns, dayconvert, devdata, diagnostic, dnrd, echo, egrep, expr, false, fgrep, free, fresetd, genuuid, gethostip, grep, gunzip, gzip, hnap, hostapd, hostname, httpd, ifconfig, insmod, iptables-restore, iwpriv, igmpproxy, ip, iptables-save, init, iptables, iwconfig, kill, killall, klogd, lld2d, ln, logger, login, ls, lsmod, mfc, mkdir, mknod, modprobe, mount, msh, mv, neaps, nsbbox, ntpclient, pfile, pidof, ping, portt, pppd, ps, psts, pwd, reboot, rgdb, rmmod, route, rgbin, rm, rndimage, rt3052esw, scheduled, sendmail, sleep, stats, sys, scut, sgi, slinktype, submit, syslog, sed, sh, smtpclient, switch, syslogd, tar, tcprequest, test, tlogs, tr, true, tc, telnetd, time, touch, trigger, ubcfg, udhcpc, umount, upnpdev, uptime, ubcom, udhcpd, uname, upnpkits, usockc, vconfig, wan, wfadev, widget, wps, wc, wfanotify, wlxmlpatch, xgi, xmldb, xmldbc, yes, zcat

cheers :)

Comment: Would this be my solution?! http://wiki.openvpn.eu/index.php/Install_Linux

Answer (score 0):

DD-WRT is available for this router. The build type is not specified but if it's anything other than "micro" it will include PPTP VPN support.

- http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/D-Link_DIR-615_rev_D3
- http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/What_is_DD-WRT%3F#File_Versions

Comment: i know very well about ddwrt and openwrt releases. but they doesnt suit for my goal. i want to learn much more about the deeper functionalities of embedded systems, in this case to hardcode it manually.